# why ajax post request is aborted and how to make it reach server Jboss 8?

Tags: ajax, extjs, jboss

Technologies used: Ajax, ExtJs, Jboss 8,Java 7

this code sends an Ajax request to the server , things works fine for 20 minutes but after that same request does not goes to server and i observe a message on fire bug console of web browser stating that request is aborted , i am using Jboss 8 as a server for my application

```
function loadAll(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'loadAllData',
        params:{
            userId:cad_userid
        },
        success: function(response){
            var incidentArray=[];
            var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            Ext.each(obj, function(event,i){
                var featureincident = createIconforincident(event);
                incidentArray.push(featureincident);                    
            });
            regenerateVectorLayerFeaturesAndPopup(map.getLayersByName(vLayer_Incidents)[0],incidentArray);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please elaborate on the question . just code is not enough

Comment: this code sends an Ajax request to the server , things works fine for 20 minutes but after that same request does not goes to server and i observe a message on fire bug console of web browser stating that request is aborted , i am using Jboss 8 as a server for my application

Comment: Same issue to me! Mine ajax requests are aborted after a few requests right away!